# ASP.NET CORE API PUT request getting 405 Method not allowed

Tags: asp.net-core, postman, put, api-design, http-status-code-405

I have created the following API PUT endpoint but when I try to hit it through postman or through the web browser it is not responding and on the web browser just says .

> HTTP ERROR 405

When I have looked up this the main reason people are suggesting as a solution is WebDAV being downloaded which I do not have turned on so it can't be that.

**PUT Requests**

```
    // PUT api/invoices/{customerId}/new
    [HttpPut("{customerId}/new")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> NewInvoice(Guid customerId, [FromBody] List<Guid> orderIds, [FromQuery] double invoiceCost)
    {
        Guid invoiceId = await invoicesRepository.newInvoice(invoiceCost, customerId);

        invoiceOrdersRepository.addInvoiceOrders(orderIds, invoiceId);

        return Ok();
    }

    // PUT api/invoices/{id}/email
    [HttpPut("{invoiceId}/email")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EmailInvoice(Guid invoiceId)
    {

        await emailMessageSender.SendEmailAsync("email@gmail.com", "Test", "Hello");

        return Ok();
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Uri's being called:

https://localhost:44393/api/invoices/b9db6db2-20e3-43da-84cc-68dcdf3a54ea/email

[image: New Invoice PUT Request]

Comment: Show the URIs being called that get that error. Or the Raw requests

Comment: Refer this Link                                                                                                                    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications

Comment: @Nkosi have updated question with URIs

Comment: 1. You said the URI being called is `/api/invoices/{customerId}/email` : But the screenshot shows you're sending request to "/api/invoices/{customerId}/new" ? 2. Could you please shows the logs and also the code of Startup ?